# undefined symbol while trying to run g_bus_own_name on Suse

Tags: linux, eclipse, shell, suse, mobaxterm

I have downloaded eclipse on my Suse enterprise and am trying to run eclipse (From MobaXterm, have terminal access only with XServer installed). I keep on getting the following error when I run ./eclipse

```
~/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/450/0/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4919.so: undefined symbol: g_bus_own_name
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer to your question by now? Could you please share it?

Comment: I didn't, I used netbeans 8.2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

[GNOME Developer: Owning Bus Names](https://developer.gnome.org/gio//2.52/gio-Owning-Bus-Names.html#g-bus-own-name) shows that **g_bus_own_name** was added in 2.26.  You don't say which version of SUSE enterprise you're running; I suspect that your SUSE version comes with an earlier GTK version. You should be able to run **rpm -q gtk2** to determine the GTK version installed on your system.